# Is the zero matrix upper and lower triangular as well as diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From what I can tell from the definitions of a lower-triangular, upper-triangular, and diagonal matrices, I've come to the conclusion that the zero matrix is in the set of all of each type of matrix.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: If an object meets the definition of three things then it is the three things. What are you confused about?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A zero square matrix is lower triangular, upper triangular, and also diagonal.

Answer (score 6):

Provided it is a square matrix.

An upper triangular matrix is one in which all entries below the main diagonal are zero. Clearly this is satisfied.

A lower triangular matrix is one in which all entries above the main diagonal are zero. Clearly this is satisfied.

A diagonal matrix is one in which all non-diagonal entries are zero. Clearly this is also satisfied.

Hence, a zero square matrix is upper and lower triangular as well as a diagonal matrix.